# Safari WebDriver: How to Click to Enable Geo Location

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am automating using Selenium Safari WebDriver and ran into a popup dialog asking to allow Geo Location:
[image: Dialog]

How do I click the "Allow" button assume that my driver is called `driver`.

Comment: See [here](https://www.guru99.com/alert-popup-handling-selenium.html) for an example.

Comment: Thank you @Thymen, I'm looking into it now.